# Error: Illegal application (Non-functional construction)

Tags: coq

I'm trying to work some proofs of the various deMorgans laws using the type constructors/eliminators from the HoTT book. I had hopped to pick through https://mdnahas.github.io/doc/Reading_HoTT_in_Coq.pdf for relevant stuff and dump it all into a .v text file. I need Elimination/Introduction rules for product, co-product and a way to set up negation. So far I have,

```
Definition idmap {A:Type} (x:A) : A := x.

Inductive prod {A B:Type} : Type := pair : A -> B -> @prod A B.

Notation "x * y" := (prod x y) : type_scope.

Section projections.
  Context {A : Type} {B : Type}.
  Definition fst (p: A * B ) :=
    match p with
      | (x , y) => x
    end.

  Definition snd (p:A * B ) :=
    match p with
      | (x , y) => y
    end.
End projections.
```

The Error on "Definition fst (p: A * B ) :=" is

```
Error: Illegal application (Non-functional construction): 
The expression "prod" of type "Type"
cannot be applied to the term
 "A" : "Type"
```

I tried searching through the error list on the Coq site but didn't find anything.

Comment: If the answer posted below helped you to resolve your issue, then it'd be nice if you accepted the answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues with your code:

- `prod`'s two `Type` arguments are declared implicit

As a consequence, the notation `"x * y"` corresponds to `prod {_} {_} x y` which will always lead to ill-typed terms: `prod {_} {_}` is a `Type` and as such it does not make sense to apply something to it.

The fix is to turn these two implicit arguments into explicit ones:

```
Inductive prod (A B:Type) : Type := pair : A -> B -> @prod A B.
```

- The notation `(x , y)` has not been declared

Once you've fixed the definition of `prod`, the definition still don't typecheck because Coq does not know what you mean by the pattern `(x, y)`. You can declare it as a new notation before your `Section projections` like so:

```
Notation "x , y" := (pair _ _ x y) (at level 10).
```